# How to find the exact length and matched string in a file using python

Tags: python

I have file contains

```
"Starting program and 
Starting program
Loading molecule...
Initialising variables...
Starting the calculation - this could take a while!
Molecule energy = 2432.6 kcal mol-1
Calculation finished. Bye!"
import sys
import re

search_string = "Starting program"
txtlength=len(search_string)
print "txtlength",txtlength
lines = open( "C:\search.txt", "r" ).readlines()
for line in lines:
    if re.search( search_string, line ):
        print line,

    else :
        print "Not found"
```

I am looking for only 2nd line in the file but ouput coming from this code is 1 line is also displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need regex for the example you show:

```
with open("C:/search.txt") as inp:
    for line in inp:
        if line.strip() == search_string:
            print line
```

Comment: Please How I can give for Upper case and lower case letters in the code

Comment: You can convert both strings to lowercase using `.lower()` when you check for equality.